# Forking a specific gem version

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, bundler

I use the `Mechanize 2.7.1` gem.  When I `bundle update`, I'm told that it's up to date.  However, at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) there have been some subsequent changes, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/commit/723bf70c82a8eea38c8e860ba2e62feb0e0fab60) that don't get pulled in when you update the gem.  How can I fork the 2.7.1 gem code that I have installed on my computer, or any specific version of the gem, for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your Gemfile with the `:git` or `:github` command (http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html) to load the gem from Github rather than from RubyGems:

```
gem 'mechanize', :github => 'sparklemotion/mechanize'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have the effect of loading the more recent version from git?  I want to keep the version I have right now as it's what my code is compatible with

Comment: @babonk Did you read the linked documentation to *:git* option ? Did you read about *:ref* and *:tag* keys ? If it won't satisfy your needs, you've probably apply selected patch(es) manually.